# I can't access the Apache Tomcat Manager?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat-manager

I know there are many of similar questions like mine. However, I spend two days exploring these questions and no one works for me.

I have Apache Tomcat 7.0.59 installed on my laptop. I can access my Apps that I developed but I can't access the manager. I got this error:

> HTTP Status 404 - /manager/html
>
> type Status report
>
> message /manager/html
>
> description The requested resource is not available.

I use this url to access it: `http://localhost:8080/manager/html`

I changed the tomcat-users.xml and server.xml as I found in the web, but still does not work.

Here is my tomcat-users.xml

```
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="role1"/>
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
<user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
<user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
<user username="admin" password="tomcat" roles="manager,manager-gui"/>
```

Here is my server.xml

```
<!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->
```

Could anyone help me? why give me this error? Is there anything wrong with the url?

Comment: Did you check that the `manager` folder exists in the `webapps` folder?

Comment: I found only a folder for manager and another for host-manager inside webapps. Both files contains .jsp pages, but there is no manager.war file.

Comment: Did you look at the log files to see if there are any issues?

Comment: Any reason you changed the `UserDatabaseRealm` to `MemoryRealm`?

Comment: Which log file? sorry, but I'm new to Tomcat. No, there is no reason  I just found MemoryRealm on some post here.

Comment: Log files are in the `logs` folder.

Comment: Hope you just posted partial files, because you're missing the `<tomcat-users>` root element of the `tomcat-users.xml` file, and many many elements of the `server.xml` file.

Comment: manager and host-manager files are empty.

Comment: Yes I ONLY post that parts that I have edited.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110686/discussion-between-f-fo-and-andreas).

Comment: I'm running the Apache Tomcat from the Eclipse. Does that make difference?

Answer (score -1):

The problem happened because I was running the Tomcat from the Eclipse. I start it again from the terminal (command line) and the problem solved.

Thank you Andreas for help.